# Wrap text inside Listbox item

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

### Issue

---

I have a **Listbox** that I have bound to an *ObservableCollection< string>*:

```
Polls = new ObservableCollection<string>();

DataSet LoadAllPolls = _publisher.GetQuizFeatures(Global.gEpisodeWS.Id);

foreach (DataRow item in LoadAllPolls.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    Polls.Add(item["Description"].ToString());
}
```

Here is the XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb_polls" Background="#ececec" BorderBrush="Transparent" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPoll}" ItemsSource="{Binding Polls}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="110"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#858585" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#858585" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="#858585"/>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Now i want the strings that are being added to the ListBox items to wrap. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple, but i don't know why is not working your code, this my `xaml`

```
<Grid Width="600" Height="Auto" >
        <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Polls}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="110"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

which is bound to an `ObservableCollection` Polls and is working fine.

```
       private void LoadPoll()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                Polls.Add("Poll" + i.ToString());
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<string> _Polls = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public ObservableCollection<string> Polls
        {
            get { return _Polls; }
            set
            {
                _Polls = value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this ItemTemplate:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: You may also need to set the horizontal scroll bar to "Never", as I believe the default for ListBox is "Auto" so it will just scroll rather than wrapping. Might be wrong though.

Comment: @Clemens I can only see 1 item in the list now and not all 3.

Comment: Works for me, though, with exactly your XAML. Setting any Scrollbar properties isn't necessary, as the Width of the ListBoxItems is set explicitly by the ItemContainerStyle.

Comment: @Clemens the item gets moved to the middle for me and therefore doesn't display anymore.

Comment: Then there must be something in your XAML or code you haven't shown us.